# Is there a way of predicting where the Mysterious Stranger is going to be?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Is there a mathematical method to figure out what room the Mysterious Stranger will go into next after we previously got him?

Comment: It's random. If you have a reliable mathematical method to predict random events, you should go to Las Vegas, not waste your time on computer games.

Comment: Well there is one, although it isn't guaranteed, my math teacher taught my class while we were "learning" probabilities for about the 7th time in my time in school, only added the idea of say a 6 sided die and rolls 1 7 times 2 3 times 3 4 times 4 4 times 5 2 times and 6 10 times then you would bet on 6 more likely than anything else for which would be next.